# Using Navigation inside TabController in StoryBoard.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to iPhone app development, I have a tabbed based app,

On first tab view I have a search form, on when I put value in search and get results in array I want get result in table but in Navigation View Controller, with a detailed view option and a button inside cell which will add cell items into favourites,

every thing is working fine, I am unable to get results in navviewcontroller table,

I am using storyboard in xcode 4.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Select the View in Storyboard that you want to add navigation and then `Editor ->Embed -> Navigation Controller`.
Then select all(View that you need in Tabbar you can also select Navigation Controller View ) the View and again `Embed` it in `Tab Bar`.
I am Also Attaching Image so u can get a good idea.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure that the form view controller is actually inside a `UINavigationController`?

**Edit:** Since you're using a storyboard, here's what you need to do. Select your form view controller and choose Editor->Embed->Navigation controller. Then add a segue from the form view controller to the table view controller, and make it a push segue, and give it an identifier, you can do all of this in right pane. After that add the navigation controller, as a view controller to the `UITabViewController`.

Comment: I guess not, its in tabView and then there is UIViewController So, I think its outside, do I have to put inside?

Comment: Well, the structure is like this. The form view controller is the first view controller in navigation stack, so it must be viewed by a navigation controller to be able to naviagate to another view controller.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I need to conver my first tabView into NavigationViewController, and put form into that, and then do the rest process.

Comment: @Kam You need to **add** your first view controller into a `UINavigationController`. Check my edit.

Comment: Also, check Ayush's answer.