# How can I switch between UIViewControllers in iOS using Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, view

I am using storyboards for a Tabbed application. Within a specific tab I need to display multiple views. I have a navigation bar containing two buttons (Prev and next); when I click on next the app should display the next View(new UIViewController not the next Tab)  and when I click on Prev the app should switch to the previous view (new UIViewController) but without leaving the selected Tab (The tabbar should stay displayed and with the same index).

[image]

I want to change the views inside the selected Tab , any one have any ideas?

Comment: Little more specification please. When you press next, do you want to present the view from the next tab but with the current tab selected? Or do you want to present a different view, specific to the current tab?

Comment: `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];` is what you are looking for???

Comment: I Want to present a different view but within the current tab . I want to present a new view but keep the Tabbar with the selected tab .

Comment: @ManchesterUnited : why you want this way? if you are moving to next view, it should show that tab selected...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859692/using-navigation-inside-tabcontroller-in-storyboard/16860072#16860072

Comment: It looks that your app is in french :)

Comment: Yes it is in French :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are truly referring to UIView and not UIViewControllers, then all you have to do is link the view to your .m file with the normal ctrl and drag method. Then create an IBAction when the button is tapped (ctrl drag the button and on type tap on action). Then there will be a method below that will be automatically called when the button is tapped. You also have to create the second view you want to display and also link it with the .m file.

So in the method:

```
{
//view1 the view you want to change, view2 the one you want to display
[_view1 setHidden:TRUE];
[_view2 setHidden:FALSE];
}
```

EDIT: For UIViewController

It can all be done through Interface Builder. Ctrl click on the Suivant button and drag it on the new UIViewController. Then click Modal and in the new UIViewController place the Tab Bar and the Top Bar. You will then have to set them again, just like what you did on your existing UIViewController. Otherwise place a navigation controller, in inspector set it as initial view controller, ctrl drag on your Tab Bar controller in IB and set it to root View Controller. This will at least have the top bar created for you. But you will then have to edit the action of the suivant button, by doing ctrl click and setting it to push. This is what I did on my xcode in a quick replication of your project and it worked perfectly. You can also avoid repeating the creation of the tab bar by going to your new UIViewContoller and doing this:

```
Editor ->Embed -> Navigation Controller
```

Let me know if this works :)

Comment: I mean an UIViewController :) sorry !

Comment: @ManchesterUnited Done, it should work now (by recreating the tab bar I also mean the current one, but the bottom advice that was also suggested by Ayush is better) :)

Comment: it works Fine Thank You  , I added a Navigation controller, Embedded it into the TabBar , the I related the other UIviewControllers to navigation controller , the Tab bar was added to the first view and I Created the actions of the buttons to make themdisplay the other UIviewsControllers . Thank You isklikas and Thank You Ayush for the link :)